# AttributeError: 'GPT2TokenizerFast' object has no attribute 'max_len'

Tags: tokenize, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers, gpt-2

I am just using the huggingface transformer library and get the following message when running run_lm_finetuning.py: AttributeError: 'GPT2TokenizerFast' object has no attribute 'max_len'. Anyone else with this problem or an idea how to fix it? Thanks!

My full experiment run:
mkdir experiments

for epoch in 5
do
python run_lm_finetuning.py 
--model_name_or_path distilgpt2 
--model_type gpt2 
--train_data_file small_dataset_train_preprocessed.txt 
--output_dir experiments/epochs_$epoch 
--do_train 
--overwrite_output_dir 
--per_device_train_batch_size 4 
--num_train_epochs $epoch
done

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ["AttributeError: 'BertTokenizerFast' object has no attribute 'max_len'" Github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8739) contains the fix:

> The `run_language_modeling.py` script is deprecated in favor of `language-modeling/run_{clm, plm, mlm}.py`.
>
> If not, the fix is to change `max_len` to `model_max_length`.

Also, `pip install transformers==3.0.2` might fix the issue since it has been reported to work for some people.

Answer (score 1):

I use this command to solve it.

```
pip install transformers==3.0.2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).